# Using Array For statistic (decimal)

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I'm new to coding here.
I am trying to use coding to show statistic for Average, Maximum and Minimum.
I have the error there they say I cannot convert `decimal[]` to `int[]`. I have commented the error below beside my code. It is one of the last few lines.
I'm required to use `Arrays` for this project and the values must be in `decimal`.

Thank you and sorry if I am doing something wrong, I am new.

```
namespace Group_Project_Final
{
    public partial class LoanRates : Form
    {
        public LoanRates()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private double Average (int [] iArray)
        {
            int total = 0;
            double average;

            for(int index=0;index<iArray.Length;index++)
            {
                total += iArray[index];
            }
            average = (double)total / iArray.Length;
            return average;
        }
        private decimal Highest (int [] iArray)
        {
            int highest = iArray[0];

            for (int index =1; index<iArray.Length;index++)
            {
                if(iArray[index]>highest)
                {
                    highest = iArray[index];
                }               
            }
            return highest;
        }
        private decimal Lowest(int [] iArray)
        {
            int lowest = iArray[0];

            for (int index =1; index<iArray.Length; index++)
            {
                if(iArray[index]<lowest)
                {
                    lowest = iArray[index];
                }
            }
            return lowest;
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Home form1 = new Home();
            form1.Show();
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal [] rates = { 1.60m, 1.65m ,1.62m, 1.55m, 1.68m, 1.58m };

            int index = 0;
            decimal highestRate; 
            decimal lowestRate;
            double averageRate;

            while(index<rates.Length)
            {
                decimal.ToInt32(rates[index]);
                index++;
            }

            highestRate = Highest(rates); //i am having the error here where they say "cannot simply convert decimal[] to int[] 
            lowestRate = Lowest(rates);
            averageRate = Average(rates); 

            txtAvg.Text = averageRate.ToString();
            txtHighest.Text = highestRate.ToString();
            txtLowest.Text = lowestRate.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly as the error states: `Highest` needs an `int[]` but `rates` is a `decimal[]`. In addition, unless this is for learning purposes then use linq's `Min`,`Max` and `Average` methods.

Comment: Also, see how [decimal.ToInt32()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.toint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) actually works.

Comment: I would update the definition of `Average(int [] iArray)` to `Average(decimal [] dArray)`. All your logic is fine, the only issue is that you are trying to convert between decimal[] and integer[].

Comment: As an aside, please don't prefix names with their type (`iArray`). That's commonly called Hungarian Notation, and is widely considered a bad practice. In C# you explicitly have to declare the _type_ of the parameter (`int[]`), so including the type as a prefix of the name is redundant. It also means you have to rename variables if you change their type (e.g. in my previous comment), and it is generally a pain to work with.

Comment: Why does your `Average` method return a `double`, but the others return a `decimal`? I'd make them all return `decimal` for consistency and because your source values *are* `decimal`s. Also note that if you *did* successfully convert the values to `Int32` that you lose the fractional part of each number.. Is that what you intend? All your method would return `1.0` in that case because `ToInt32` simply truncates the decimal.

Answer (score 4):

Just putting it out there,

You could reduce 90% of your code by just using the BCL methods of linq.

It solves your casting and type problems instantly

```
using System.Linq;

...

private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   decimal[] rates = { 1.60m, 1.65m, 1.62m, 1.55m, 1.68m, 1.58m };
   txtAvg.Text = rates.Max().ToString();
   txtHighest.Text = rates.Min().ToString();
   txtLowest.Text = rates.Average().ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need `decimal` Array, change your function according to `decimal`.

```
private double Average(decimal[] iArray)
{
  decimal total = 0;
  double average;

  for (int index = 0; index < iArray.Length; index++)
  {
    total += iArray[index];
  }
  average = (double)total / iArray.Length;
  return average;
}
private decimal Highest(decimal[] iArray)
{
  decimal highest = iArray[0];

  for (int index = 1; index < iArray.Length; index++)
  {
    if (iArray[index] > highest)
    {
      highest = iArray[index];
    }
  }
  return highest;
}
private decimal Lowest(decimal[] iArray)
{
  decimal lowest = iArray[0];

  for (int index = 1; index < iArray.Length; index++)
  {
    if (iArray[index] < lowest)
    {
      lowest = iArray[index];
    }
  }
  return lowest;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Right now your functions `Lowest` and `Highest` take in `int` arrays and not `decimal` arrays as you are giving it. Right now your line `decimal.ToInt32(rates[index]);` does nothing as it is just solves for the equivalent `int` value of that index but doesn't assign it anywhere and thus just gets lost. You'd need to either create a new integer array and add each value to it through your loop instead, something like this:

```
int[] integerRates = new int[6];
while(index<rates.Length)
        {
            integerRates[index] = decimal.ToInt32(rates[index]);
            index++;
        }
highestRate = Highest(integerRates); 
lowestRate = Lowest(integerRates);
averageRate = Average(integerRates);
```

Or change the input parameter of your other functions to accept `decimal` arrays instead (as per Masoomian's answer), which would also deem your `while` loop redundant. This is likely the better way of handling it as you won't lose accuracy on your decimals.

The best solution would be to use `Linq` as TheGeneral suggested. Although I suspect this is for a school project where they may want to teach loops and if statements.

Comment: I'd think the whole `decimal.ToInt32` part, even if assigned somewhere, would be unwanted anyways. The fractional portion of each number would be lost and the OP clearly has non-integral (ex. 1.65) values in their source

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 You're right, dropping it is certainly better. I just wanted to show how that function worked and include a solution which basically solved it in the way she envisioned it (just w.o the bug).